# SQL Invoice Query Performance converting Credits to negative numbers

Tags: sql-server

I have a 3rd party database that contains Invoice data I need to report on.  The Quantity and Amount Fields are stored as Positive numbers regardless of whether the "invoice" is a Credit Memo or actual Invoice.  There is a single character field that contains the Type "I" = Invoice, "R" = Credit.

In a report that is equating 1.4 million records, I need to sum this data, so that Credits subtract from the total and Invoices add to the total, and I need to do this for 8 different columns in the report (CurrentYear, PreviousYear, etc)

My problem is performance of the many different ways to achieve this.

The Best performing seems to be using a CASE statement within the equation like so:

```
Case WHEN ARH.AccountingYear - 2 = @iCurrentYear THEN ARL.ShipQuantity * (CASE WHEN InvoiceType = 'R' THEN -1 ELSE 1 END) ELSE 0 END as PPY_INVOICED_QTY
```

But code readable wise, this is super ugly since I have to do it to 8 different columns, performance is good, runs against all 1.4M records in 16 seconds.

Using a Scalar UDF kills performance

```
Case WHEN ARH.AccountingYear - 2 = @iCurrentYear THEN ARL.ShipQuantity * dbo.fn_GetMultiplier(ARH.InvoiceType) ELSE 0 END as PPY_INVOICED_QTY
```

Takes almost 5 minutes.  So can't do that.

Other options I can think of would be:

1. Multiple levels of Views, use a new view to add a Multiplier column, then SELECT from that and do the multiplication using the new column
2. Build a table that has 2 columns and 2 records, R, -1 and I, 1, and join it based on InvoiceType, but this seems excessive.

Any other ideas I am missing, or suggestions on best practice for this sort of thing?  I cannot change the stored data, that is established by the 3rd party application.

Comment: Could you alter the schema and add a computed column based on the invoice type? It would make it more readable but might also increase performance.

Comment: Unfortunately I am not allowed to alter the 3rd party tables in any way without void the support contract.

Comment: In that case one or more Views is probably your best bet. Depending on what you are including you might be able to make an [Indexed view](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191432(v=sql.110).aspx) which might give you a slight performance boost.

Comment: Alternatively if the report users are OK with semi-stale data you could create your own table and load with the data in a form that is suitable for reporting. You can aggregate it too so it is no longer transaction based. In many cases this is acceptable. Depending on your requirements you can then figure out how old the data can be and update it based on that frequency, like with a Sql Job that runs every XX. Its a trade off, either slow performance with real time data or slightly older data but instant results.

Comment: @Igor, Actually it is currently done out of stale data that through many levels of Stored Procedures and Views takes 9 minutes to populate (And uses 52 different SQL Objects).  I am attempting to convert it to Live data and make it easier to understand, Currently only accessing 8 SQL Objects.  Thus my hesitation to make the code hard to read, or adding extra layers of Views where not absolutely required.  Always a balancing act though.  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to go with the multiple views as Igor suggested, actually using the nested version, even though readability is lower, maintenance is easier due to only 1 named view instead of 2.  Performance is similar to the 8 different case statements, so overall running in just under 20 seconds.

Thanks for the insights.